# How to get user's location to for post item accordingly

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Hello everyone i'm building an app similar to "Letgo" in other word an e-commerce app where i need to get the user's location in order to post items around the user's location.. I know it has to do with core location.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, use CoreLocation... what else?

Answer (score 0):

CoreLocation has a function called requestLocation that will cause its delegate method didUpdateLocation to get called.

Correct me if I am wrong, but it sounds like you might be unfamiliar with CoreLocation and MapKit. Those are the 2 main frameworks you will need. By the way importing mapKit automatically imports CoreLocation.

I would recommend looking up RayWenderlich.com. He has an intro to CoreLocation and MapKit series. I think that series will cover in more detail than I can do here most of what you will need to know.

Comment: I'm Actually familiar with Mapkit and a not that much of CoreLoction. I will definitely check the series. Thanks so much CodelsFun!